# Select or create external file using Storage Access Framework (SAF)

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve opening an existing file, or creating a new file with SAF on the external and without the user having to install anything additional other than my apk.

On my Pixel 3 with Android 10, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE throws an exception indicating there's not activity to handle this (I'm left wondering why this would be?).
`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=vnd.android.document/directory (has extras) }`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:.myfolder");
    intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);

    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, READ_DIRECTORY_CODE);
```

ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT seem to work appropriately.

However, if I:

1. Start the intent with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and the file doesn't already exist, the user is stuck without being able to select anything or create a new one.

   ```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:.myfolder/myfile.json");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myfile.json");
   intent.setType("application/json");

   activity.startActivityForResult(intent, READ_DIRECTORY_CODE);
   ```
2. Start the intent with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT and the file DOES exist, the user is only give the option to create a new one which overwrites the old.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT); //Opens the create file UI
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:.myfolder");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myfile.json");
   intent.setType("application/json");

   activity.startActivityForResult(intent, READ_DIRECTORY_CODE);
   ```

If I could tell the folder and file exists before starting the intent, I'd have something usable.
I can't seem to get that to work either using DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, uri)
Note, I got the URI from the open command, at a time the file actually existed.  ie. "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:.myfolder"
I get only Invalid URI exceptions when I try it.

```
    try {
        Uri folderUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:.myfolder");
        exists = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, folderUri).exists();  //This line throws the URI exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Any ideas on any of these obstacles?

Comment: `On my Pixel 3 with Android 10, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE throws an exception` Hard to believe. Which exception? Please show your code.

Comment: `if I: 1. Start the intent with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and the file doesn't already exist,` ??? Which file? Please show your code.

Comment: `If I could tell the folder and file exists before starting the intent` ??? Which folder? Which file? Please show your code for both actions so we know what you are doing.

Comment: @blackapps I edited the question to show code

Comment: `If I could tell the folder and file exists before starting the intent, I'd have something usable` Buit whar? You still did not tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `Note, I got the URI from the open command` Open command?

Comment: `EXTRA_INITIAL_DIR` does not work for ACTION_OPEN__DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE throws an exception indicating there's not activity to handle this` Do you mean an `ActivitNotFoundException`? Then please be exact. You get this exception because of the statement `intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);`. Remove it. Also the CATEGORY_OPENABLE is of no use there.

Comment: Also for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT the problem that no file is pickable does not come from EXTRA_INITIAL_DIR but from `intent.setType("application/json");` Also `intent.setType("*/json");` does the same. Better use `intent.setType("*.*");`

Answer (score 0):

The following @blackapps comment gave me the answer to the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE part of the question.

You get this exception because of the statement intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);. Remove it. Also the CATEGORY_OPENABLE is of no use there.